# How to see all controls linked to automation clip in FL Studio 20?

Tags: fl-studio

I know how to find and setup automation links in Remote control settings of control. 
I also know about Current project/Initialized controls list, where i can find list of all automated controls in project.

But how can I go opposite way: get list of all automated controls for one specific automation clip? Ok, clip name contains target control info by default, but i can link more than one control to this clip...

Answer (score 0):

- Right-click the automation clip in the Playlist window and select "Edit events"
- In Event Editor, the automated controls will be under the "Remote" in the "Remote control assignments" section.

Or right-click the automation clip and select "Remote control editor." The linked controls will be displayed as automation curves.

Answer (score 0):

In FL Studio 20.9 and later, clicking the automation clip entry in the channel rack opens the new automation clip editor, which plainly lists all link targets.